# Can I exclude fields from lomboks @Data annotation?

Tags: java, spring, getter-setter, lombok

Lets say this is my class. And I want getters and setters for all fields except the Date. Is the a way to exclude?

```
@Data
public class User {
    String first;
    String last;
    String email;
    Date dob;
    Boolean active;
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think this is the only way to hide:

```
@Getter(value=AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Setter(value=AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
private Date dob;
```

or maybe better with `AccessLevel.NONE` like Ken Chan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54782694/6413377) suggests

so overriding the access level. However this does not hide it from constructors.

Also you can make tricks with inheritance. Define class like:

```
public class Base {
    // @Getter if you want
    private Date dob;
}
```

and let your `User` to extend that:

```
@Data
public class User extends Base {
    private String first;
    private String last;
    private String email;
    private Boolean active;
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Well , or better yet use `AccessLevel.NONE` to completely make it does not generate getter or setter. No private getter or setter will be generated.

```
@Getter(value=AccessLevel.NONE)
@Setter(value=AccessLevel.NONE)
private Date dob;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using the following annotations:

```
    @Getter(value=AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Setter(value=AccessLevel.NONE)
    private LocalDate dob;
```

It is also better to use a LocalDate instead of Date. Date is a deprecated API.

@pirho, your example still creates the getter and setter but makes them private.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure it's best practice, but what I did when I had to exclude `@ManyToMany` fields from `@EqualsAndHashCode` (to prevent stackoverflow) is this

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class User implements UserDetails {
// ...
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
                            @JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
                                @JoinColumn(name = "role", referencedColumnName = "role")})
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Role> authorities;
```

In other words, I explicitly added an `@EqualsAndHashCode` so that I could put an `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude` annotation at the `@ManyToMany` field. You can do a similar thing with your getters ans setters. It works